# Android: SharedPreferencesImpl-load Exception, SharedPreferences getting crashed

Tags: android, crash, sharedpreferences, fatal-error

I am not sure at which point my application getting crash, I have stored application states in SharedPreferences like **isUserLoggedIn**, **userId** but not stored any lengthy data in SharedPreferences.

**Crash log:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: SharedPreferencesImpl-load
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: src.length=8192 srcPos=1 dst.length=8192 dstPos=0 length=-1
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.fillBuffer(KXmlParser.java:1489)
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.skip(KXmlParser.java:1574)
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.parseStartTag(KXmlParser.java:1049)
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:369)
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readThisMapXml(XmlUtils.java:574)
    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readThisValueXml(XmlUtils.java:817)
    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readValueXml(XmlUtils.java:751)
    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readMapXml(XmlUtils.java:490)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.loadFromDiskLocked(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:120)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$000(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:52)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$1.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:91)
```

**Edit 1:**

```
private void setUserStates(boolean isUserLoggedIn, int userId){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("My_App", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isUserLoggedIn", isUserLoggedIn);
        editor.putInt("userId", userId);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private boolean getIsUserLoggedIn(){
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("My_App", MODE_PRIVATE);
        return  prefs.getBoolean("isUserLoggedIn", false);
    }

    private int getUserId(){
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("My_App", MODE_PRIVATE);
        return  prefs.getInt("userId", 0);
    }
```

Please share your thoughts on the same.

Comment: I think you're storing a Huge data in Preference.

Comment: @MD, no I am storing any huge data, I am just storing application states, userid. I have stored 10 values in Sharedprefences.

Comment: @HirenPatel post some code how you store and how you retrieve ?

Comment: @MD, edited with Edit 1, please check.

Comment: Where you're executing this in Activity or in Fragment ? becoz you're directly using getSharedPreferences(...)

Comment: @MD, this code is for Activity.

Comment: @HirenPatel Which API Version device Are you use ??

Comment: @Ironman, API level 18.

Comment: @HirenPatel Your code seems ok. Better to clear cache and try again. May be something wrong to writing data in Preferences becoz it's ultimately writing data in xml with Tag

Comment: @MD, yes, let me do that, hopefully issue not occur.

Comment: I would pull the shared preferences XML file from the app's data directory to see if there's something obviously wrong with it. Directly pulling it requires rooting / emulator; indirectly requires some code in your app to copy it to a public place e.g. in external storage.

Comment: @laalto, yes that would be option that what issue has been occured